# Theano maximum likelihood for geometric brownian motion

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

I'm trying to do maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) for a geometric brownian motion with Theano. I know, Theano is primarily a ML library, but it *should* work... (of course I'm just trying out Theano and my eventual goal is to do MLE for a slightly more complicated model....)

Writing math at SO is a bitch so look up GBM e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion).

Here's the Theano code, which is slightly modified from the logistic regression example in the Theano tutorial:

```
training_steps = 1000
dt = 1/390
NT = len(Xdata)
rng = np.random
rate = 0.001

# Declare Theano symbolic variables
X = T.vector("X")
dX = T.vector("dX")
mu = theano.shared(rng.randn(), name="mu")
sigma2 = theano.shared(rng.random(), name="sigma2")

print("Initial model:")
print(mu.get_value())
print(sigma2.get_value())

# Construct Theano expression graph

eps = (dX - mu*dt*X)/X
summand1 = eps**2
loghood = summand1.sum()/sigma2/dt + NT*T.log(sigma2)
gmu, gsigma2 =  T.grad(loghood, [mu, sigma2])

# Compile
train = theano.function(
          inputs=[X,dX],
          outputs=[loghood],
          updates=((mu, mu - rate * gmu), (sigma2, sigma2 - rate * gsigma2)))

# Train
costlist = []
mulist = []
siglist = []
for i in range(training_steps):
    cost = train(Xdata, dXdata)
    costlist.append(cost[0])
    mulist.append(mu.get_value())
    siglist.append(sigma2.get_value())

print("Final model:")
print(mu.get_value())
print(sigma2.get_value())

plot(costlist)
```

- loghood is the log likelihood, which should be minimized w.r.t mu and sigma2
- Xdata is simulated from a GBM, dXdata[n] = Xdata[n+1] - Xdata[n]
- autodifferentiation should work OK, I also tried putting the gradients by hand
- costlist, mulist, siglist were added for debugging purposes

So what I get is that the train function evaluates OK for the initial mu, sigma2, but right at step 2 where the mu, sigma2 are updated as per the gradients, the train function seems to backfire by giving either crazy numbers or nan:s...

I compared the result with exact MLE and also minimization by scipy.optimize.minimize, which both work just fine. I think the problem is somewhere in the "loghood" above, but I just can't figure it out...

**So can anyone please figure out where the code goes wrong?**

Comment: This problem can be frequently "fixed" by lowered the learning rate. Can you try it with a learning rate of 0.0001

Comment: That alone didn't completely fix it, but almost... the loghood function depends quadratically on mu, but *inverse* quadratically on sigma2, so they need different learning rates! I got it now, although I really need to think about the learning rate/ minimization to cover lots of different values for mu and sigma2... anyway, thanks nouiz!

Comment: I mean inverse quadratically for small sigma2... still get funny stuff when trying to estimate for simulations with different parameters... probably because the dependence on sigma2 is quite comlicated. Anyway, I need to think about the gradient descent!